# Error using an object as the parameter of the constructor for a class

Tags: c++, constructor, pure-virtual

We're learning c++ in the last 2 weeks of the course and its on the final in 2 days :) , so I am a beginner. I am familiar with C.

Here is the part of the assignment that is relevant:

```
Part 1 [20 points]
Reading material:
Copy constructor: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-cpp/
References (the & symbol): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Write a class Point representing a point in 2d.
The class will have the following public methods:
// constructor - sets the coordinates to be x,y
Point( int x, int y)
// copy constructor - creates a new point with the same
coordinates
Point(Point &copy)
// getters
int getX()
int getY()
// setters
void setX()
void setY()
// prints to screen the coordinates in the format (x,y)
void print()
```

My Implementation of:

Point.hpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point { 
   private: 
   int x, y; 

public: 
    // Parameterized Constructor 
    Point(int x1, int y1); 

    ~Point();

    Point (const Point &p2);

    int getX();

    int getY(); 


    void setX(int x2);


    void setY(int y2);

    void print();
};
```

Point.cpp

```
#include "Point.hpp"

Point::Point(int x1, int y1)
    { 
        x = x1; 
        y = y1; 
    } 
Point::Point (const Point &p2)
    {
        x = p2.x;
        y = p2.y;
    }

int Point::getX()
    { 
        return x; 
    } 

int Point::getY()
    { 
        return y; 
    } 

void Point::setX(int x2)
    {
      x = x2;
    }

void Point::setY(int y2)
    {
      y = y2;
    }

void Point::print()
    {
        cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")";
    }
```

**The part of the Question I am stuck on**

```
Part 2 [20 points]
Reading material:
Abstract classes and pure virtual methods:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Write an abstract class GeometricShape representing an abstract geometric
shape. The class will have the following public methods:
// Constructor: gets a coordinate. The purpose of the
coordinate depends on the specific shape
GeometricShape(Point coord)
// returns the area of the shape
// returns 0 as default. To be implemented in each
concrete shape
virtual float getArea() { return 0 ; }
// returns the perimeter of the shape
// returns 0 as default. To be implemented in each
concrete shape
virtual float getPerimeter() { return 0 ; }
// virtual method. To be implemented in each concrete
method
virtual void print() = 0 ;
```

My Implementation of:

```
GeometricShape.hpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Point.hpp"

using namespace std;

class GeometricShape { 

private:
    Point point;

public: 
    // Parameterized Constructor 
    GeometricShape(Point coord); 

    virtual float getArea();

    virtual float getPerimeter(); 

    virtual void print();
};
```

GeometricShape.cpp (**this is what wont compile**)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GeometricShape.hpp"


GeometricShape::GeometricShape(Point coord)
{
    point = coord;
}


float GeometricShape:: getArea()
{
    return 0;
}

float GeometircShape::getPerimeter()
{
    return 0;
}

void GeometricShape::print() = 0;

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Error message when compiled on Linux Ubunto 18.04.3 (university lab remotely accessed, assignments required to compile on linux in the lab)

Error message:

```
gsg27@csil-cpu5:~/sfuhome/cmpt-125/5$ g++ GeometricShape.cpp
GeometricShape.cpp: In constructor ‘GeometricShape::GeometricShape(Point)’:
GeometricShape.cpp:5:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘Point::Point()’
 GeometricShape::GeometricShape(Point coord)
                                           ^
In file included from GeometricShape.hpp:2:0,
                 from GeometricShape.cpp:2:
Point.hpp:15:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(const Point&)
     Point (const Point &p2);
     ^~~~~
Point.hpp:15:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Point.hpp:11:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(int, int)
     Point(int x1, int y1);
     ^~~~~
Point.hpp:11:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
GeometricShape.cpp: At global scope:
GeometricShape.cpp:16:7: error: ‘GeometircShape’ has not been declared
 float GeometircShape::getPerimeter()
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
GeometricShape.cpp:21:32: error: function ‘virtual void GeometricShape::print()’ is initialized like a variable
 void GeometricShape::print() = 0;
                                ^
```

**extra info**
I also tried this implementation, but thought i might be overthinking it. You can look at it if it helps understand my confusion .

GeometricShape.hpp

```
" "
GeometricShape(const Point &coord); 
""
```

GeometricShape.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GeometricShape.hpp"


GeometricShape::GeometricShape(const Point &coord)
{
    Point p = new Point(coord.getX(),coord.getY());
} 
.
.
.
```

Error Message:

```
gsg27@csil-cpu5:~/sfuhome/cmpt-125/5$ g++ GeometricShape.cpp
GeometricShape.cpp: In constructor ‘GeometricShape::GeometricShape(const Point&)’:
GeometricShape.cpp:5:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘Point::Point()’
 GeometricShape::GeometricShape(const Point &coord)
                                                  ^
In file included from GeometricShape.hpp:2:0,
                 from GeometricShape.cpp:2:
Point.hpp:15:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(const Point&)
     Point (const Point &p2);
     ^~~~~
Point.hpp:15:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Point.hpp:11:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(int, int)
     Point(int x1, int y1);
     ^~~~~
Point.hpp:11:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
GeometricShape.cpp:7:33: error: passing ‘const Point’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  Point p = new Point(coord.getX(),coord.getY());
                                 ^
In file included from GeometricShape.hpp:2:0,
                 from GeometricShape.cpp:2:
Point.hpp:17:9: note:   in call to ‘int Point::getX()’
     int getX();
         ^~~~
GeometricShape.cpp:7:46: error: passing ‘const Point’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  Point p = new Point(coord.getX(),coord.getY());
                                              ^
In file included from GeometricShape.hpp:2:0,
                 from GeometricShape.cpp:2:
Point.hpp:19:9: note:   in call to ‘int Point::getY()’
     int getY();
         ^~~~
GeometricShape.cpp:7:12: error: conversion from ‘Point*’ to non-scalar type ‘Point’ requested
  Point p = new Point(coord.getX(),coord.getY());
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
GeometricShape.cpp: At global scope:
GeometricShape.cpp:11:1: error: ‘virtual’ outside class declaration
 virtual float GeometricShape:: getArea()
 ^~~~~~~
GeometricShape.cpp:16:15: error: ‘GeometircShape’ has not been declared
 virtual float GeometircShape::getPerimeter()
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
GeometricShape.cpp:16:1: error: ‘virtual’ outside class declaration
 virtual float GeometircShape::getPerimeter()
 ^~~~~~~
GeometricShape.cpp:21:1: error: ‘virtual’ outside class declaration
 virtual void GeometricShape::print() = 0;
 ^~~~~~~
GeometricShape.cpp:21:40: error: function ‘virtual void GeometricShape::print()’ is initialized like a variable
 virtual void GeometricShape::print() = 0;
                                        ^
```

Comment: From the first batch of error messages, you don't have a default constructor for `Point`, you have a typo in your class name, and that's not how you declare a pure virtual function.

Comment: Thank you for the input. is "Point::Point(int x1, int y1) " in my point.cpp defining the constructor wrong? a typo in which class name? And what am i doing wrong with declaring the virtual pure function?

Comment: You define a constructor that takes 2 parameters but not a default constructor (`Point::Point()`).  The class name in the `getPerimeter` function definition.  Pure virtual goes in the class declaration, as listed at the end of your "Question I am stuck on" section: `virtual void print() = 0;`

Comment: thank you! will do all those things. ah ok. so i shouldnt even have anything in Geometricshape.cpp except the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

The "`= 0`" syntax for a pure virtual function is only allowed in the class definition, not at the definition of the function outside the class.

And for a pure virtual function other than a destructor, an actual definition of the function is optional, so you likely don't need to define `GeometricShape::print()` in your source file at all.

Comment: thank you! but any idea why I'm getting the error that says i dont have a consturctor for Point?

Comment: Im doing them just because the prof seems to require a .hpp and .cpp file. is there anything else wrong with my declarations or definitions?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're missing the default constructor for the class `Point`. In the GeometricShape constructor: `GeometricShape::GeometricShape(Point coord)`, `coord` is supposed to be initialized by the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

After taking in all of the help above, another question, and consulting my professor:

It should be implemented as follows, and is working correctly

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.hpp"

using namespace std;

class GeometricShape { 

private:
    Point point;
    float area;
    float perimeter;

public: 
    // Parameterized Constructor 
    GeometricShape(Point coord) :  point(coord.getX(), coord.getY())  // initialize the data field
    {
      area = 0;
      perimeter = 0;
    }

    virtual float getArea();

    virtual float getPerimeter(); 

    virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

Note, Because it is an abstract class, I found it less confusing as a beginner to make it all one file instead of separating it into a hpp and cpp file.

Comment: I will accept this as the correct answer unless anyone has any objections